# Use "..." instead of a scroller when text get cut off

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

The menu is resizeable, so the position of the "..." should be dynamic depending of how much space the text has.

how do I achieve this?

update: the TextBox in my case is inside a ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 2):

Try with *TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"*.
Ex:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Whatever}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

Comment: It goes well with "TextBlock"s alone. but when my textbox is inside a ListBoxItem, as in my case, it doesn't seem to work... any solution?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/781625ce-9681-454c-98a0-9f6f8c81684d/listboxitem-text-with-ellipsis?forum=wpf

Comment: I guess you have a `ScrollViewer` that wraps the `ItemsPresenter`. Check the `ControlTemplate` of `ListBox`. Or, maybe, you have set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"` on `ListBox`. Remove it, if exists.